# How can I detect the remote operating system?

Tags: nmap, tools, fingerprinting

Is it possible to detect the operating system type remotely from another system using any tools like `nmap` without admin privileges? What are the other alternatives for achieving this?

Comment: More details please? You can use nmap to scan the target os and it will make a good guess.... php scripts can also do it using $_SESSION[HTTP_USER_AGENT] but they would have to visit the page.

Comment: Here is a link that explains how nmap can perform OS detection and the appropriate command syntax. https://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html

Comment: You might find the [`p0f`](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f3/) utility useful for this sort of thing.

Comment: No OS detection is performed when not using root user, no traceroute either.
Yes you will be able to perform -A scan, but only with service discovery, just as you would with -sV flag.

Comment: Do you have a reference or a source that backs up the claim that "No OS detection is performed when not using root user"? This is the whole point of the question.

Answer (score 15):

Using nmap:

```
sudo nmap -O <target>
```

Or if they block your ping probes you can do:

```
sudo nmap -O <target> -Pn
```

Sometimes you still get fake results and you should try doing an aggressive scan (can be detected and blocked by the firewall).

```
sudo nmap -A <target>
```

Comment: OP asks explicitly for methods that work without admin privileges. I don't know why OP does, but this does not answer the question.

Comment: If I use  "sudo nmap -O <target>" or "sudo nmap -A <target>" it prompts for password. My intention to find the OS type without using admin privileges and any passwords.

Comment: If I use "nmap -O <target> -Pn" it says replies as "TCP/IP fingerprinting (for os scan) requires root privileges.

Answer (score 4):

You could use use the **-T4** option together with the **-A**. No  sudo is required (Tested on Ubuntu).

```
$ nmap -T4 -A 192.168.0.0/24
```

Would return for instance:

```
 Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.95
 Host is up (0.00060s latency).
 Not shown: 996 closed ports
 PORT STATE SERVICE VERSION
 22/tcp open ssh OpenSSH 5.9p1 Debian 5ubuntu1 (protocol 2.0)
 | ssh-hostkey: 1024 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:6c (DSA)
 |_2048 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:6c (RSA)
 80/tcp open http nginx 1.1.19
 |_http-title: 403 Forbidden
 |_http-methods: No Allow or Public header in OPTIONS response (status code 405)
 111/tcp open rpcbind
 | rpcinfo:
 | program version port/proto service
 | 100000 2,3,4 111/tcp rpcbind
 | 100000 2,3,4 111/udp rpcbind
 | 100003 2,3,4 2049/tcp nfs
 | 100003 2,3,4 2049/udp nfs
 | 100005 1,2,3 46448/tcp mountd
 | 100005 1,2,3 52408/udp mountd
 | 100021 1,3,4 35394/udp nlockmgr
 | 100021 1,3,4 57150/tcp nlockmgr
 | 100024 1 49363/tcp status
 | 100024 1 51515/udp status
 | 100227 2,3 2049/tcp nfs_acl
 |_ 100227 2,3 2049/udp nfs_acl
 2049/tcp open nfs (nfs V2-4) 2-4 (rpc #100003)
 Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:kernel
```

The **-A** tells nmap to perform OS checking and version checking. The **-T4** is for the speed template, these templates are what tells nmap how quickly to perform the scan. The speed template ranges from 0 for slow and stealthy to 5 for fast and obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the nmap smb-os-discovery.nse script it should for the most part give you the right answers. It doesn't work on some versions of windows 10 though.

> nmap --script smb-os-discovery.nse -p445 127.0.0.1